# how to check type for java stack trace in javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I have a java exception stack trace from server, and I wanted to check type of root cause of exception in javascript and display appropriate error message. I used instanceof, and typeof but no luck. Any help?

Example

```
if(response.stack instanceof TimeoutException){
console.log('timeout');
}
```

`response.stack` has stacktrace from java excpetion.

Comment: At the point that you have a stack trace received from a server, in a response object in javascript, you have a series of text lines, not any sort of java object. Any intelligence you want to apply to those text lines will have to be coded directly in javascript using text processing methods (substring, replace, compare, etc).

Comment: @Stobor understand, thanks for the information.